# Why React renders props.children even when it can be avoided?

Tags: reactjs

How exactly react works with children props?

An example below Demo component will fail with NPE on the someArray iteration when it is null. Idea behind Wrapper  component is to protect the case when there is no data - here I just show message 'working...' but normally it can be extended to anything, spinner for example, or progress bar. Also, in this example, even if I'll fix it with:

```
{someArray && someArray.map((arrayValue) => <li>{arrayValue}</li>)}
```

In case of someArray null react WILL do unnecessary rendering of everyhing inside Wrapper which is not very smart.

The problem as I see it is that react **always** renders children of Wrapper component, even if it can skip it. What stops react from having children as function that does render it content on demand instead?

```
const Demo = () => {
    const someArray = null; // will fail with NPE
    //const someArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']; // will render content

    return(
        <Wrapper isWorking={someArray === null}>
            <h1>Inside</h1>
            <ul>
                {someArray.map((arrayValue) => <li>{arrayValue}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = ({ isWorking, children }) => {
    if( isWorking ){
        return <div>working...</div>
    }else{
        return <div>{children}</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: `even if it can skip it ` where u r  skipping it?

Comment: Well, based on the props you could conditionally render the children. Essentially only what is returned from the `render()` method will be rendered. Moreover not doing a `null` check on `someArray` is more of a design issue.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I don't skip it. I expect react to render body of Wrapper ONLY when it is need to be rendered, and in case of isWorking set to true there is no need to render children, so it can be skipped, but apparently is not. Which cases react to render markup that will never be displayed. Well, by saying "I expect" I do understand that it is NOT working this way, so it more a question why react is designed this way? Are there some serious reasons for that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozJddz?editors=0010 Check here if you use JSX for react, you are able to apply conditional rendering in children. For your case, it should be using (someArray === null) && <h1>Inside</h1>... However I have no idea how to achieve this without using JSX. In case you wanna switch check this- https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html